# Dropdown search with blacked out page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to show a search with appears below the navigation after I click on the search button. Everything below the search should have a dark overlay.

This is my code so far: https://codepen.io/cray_code/pen/pVowEL

The problem is, that the navigation is also below the dark area. I tried it with `z-index` but that would only work with `position:absolute`...

And I don't know the height of the navbar because it could change.
Is there any elegant solution to do this?

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button with data-target
  </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="container">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#collapseExample:after {background: rgba(47, 47, 47, 0.2); position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; content: ''; z-index: 1000;}
```

Comment: added the code in the question

Comment: did you try overflow:hidden; ?

Comment: @LakinduGunasekara no, how sould I use it?

Comment: @Cray i think if you give a minus value to z-index, problem should be solved. check the answer given below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `z-index: -1` to css, instead of using z-index as 1000. When the button is clicked, it won't cover the nav bar. Try the snippet below.

```css
#collapseExample:after {
  background: rgba(47, 47, 47, 0.2);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button with data-target
  </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="container">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm, it's working in your example but not on my page.... have to check that. is there anything I could do about the pause before the whole page gets darker?

Comment: it worked in the https://codepen.io/cray_code/pen/pVowEL one as well though. Maybe some other dependency cause this issue?

Comment: thats great cray

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
nav.navbar {
    z-index: 123;
}

#collapseExample:after {
    z-index:  1;
}
```